# How to access variables from one plugin in another

Tags: pages, admin

Intro:
My company offers products as well as services, and we currently use Woocommerce to sell both. I would like to keep products separate from our services, as we treat our products similar to food orders at a restaurant with a timer in a queue. Currently we monitor our incoming orders during business hours and start working on our product creation as soon as an order with it comes in.

I have creates a submenu in Woocommerce Entitled "Products" and hooked it to a callback function "product_page" to render the admin page. This is where I am stuck. I need to access all of the Woocommerce orders that fall under the category "Product" and display them here, essentially as a clone of the default Woocommerce order admin area, but with a few mods.

I am using Gravity Forms Product Add ons for Woocommerce which is where all my Product data lies.

Question:
How do I access the variables, or make use of the functions in other plugin class files? I need to make a custom database table that combines the gravity form entry data with custom data that I can then display on my admin area "product_page" as a queue of currently active orders needing to be created.

I don't understand the scope of the variables in other plugins, as I look through plugin file templates to emulate them, but they use variables that aren't defined in the file. The only explanation I can think of is that somewhere in their files they have used a hook or something to call their template files, and have passed variables that way.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer to the main question. **You cannot access other plugin's variables.** If they're programmed using Object Oriented Programming pattern, then maybe you will be able to access a few public variables. But it is not the standard WordPress way.

The best way to do it is by using **actions** and **filters**.

If you want to show products that match a certain condition, I suggest you create new **admin menu page**, then use **WPDB** to do custom SQL query there.

And if you don't know how the WooCommerce and Gravity Forms data is structured, just browse the database using **phpmyadmin** or something that you're familiar with, and see the structure there.

I hope it helps.